# Is Jaskowski's paraconsistent system moderate if sparked?

Tags: lo.logic

Stanislaw Jaskowski published a non-adjunctive paraconsistent logic, which does not have the inference rule $\vdash A \ \& \  \vdash B\Rightarrow \ \vdash A\wedge B$. The paper first appeared  in Polish: *Rachunek zdań dla systemow dedukcyjnych sprzecznych*, Studia Societatis Scientiarum Torunensis, Sectio A, Vol. I, No. 5, 1948, 57-77. The last English translation is [A Propositional Calculus for Inconsistent Deductive Systems](https://apcz.umk.pl/LLP/article/view/LLP.1999.003), in Logic and Logical Philosophy, Vol. 7, 35-56, 1999.

Let logic T be *sparked* just if it for some sentence $A$ has $\vdash_T A$ as well as $\vdash_T \lnot A$.

Let CL be classical logic.

Let logic T be moderate just if $\vdash_T B \Rightarrow \ \not\vdash_{CL}\lnot B$.

Let J+ be a minimal sparking of Jaskowski's system J.

Is J+ moderate?

Comment: @Henry I corrected.